# Conditionally update R tibble values based on other values in the row

Tags: r, tibble

I have a tibble with NA and "1" values, and I need to add in a "1" for all values in a row that are between two "1" values less than 4 columns apart (i.e. 3 or fewer columns apart).  For example, take this example tibble:

```
# Example Tibble
ex_input <- tibble( "A" = c(1, NA, NA, NA), 
             "B" = c(NA, NA, 1, 1), 
             "C" = c(1, 1, NA, NA),
             "D" = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
             "E" = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
             "F" = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
             "G" = c(1, 1, NA, NA),
             "H" = c(1, NA, NA, 1),
             "I" = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
             "J" = c(1, NA, 1, 1))
```

Which looks like:

```
> print(ex_input)
# A tibble: 4 x 10
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
4    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA     1
```

What I need at the end is for an output in which a "1" is added - in this example - to B1, D2, C2, E2, and I2 because those are all in a row between two "1" values less than 4 columns apart.  Like so:

```
> print(output)
# A tibble: 4 x 10
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2    NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
4    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried?

Comment: You probably want to transpose this so you can work along the columns instead of within rows.  E.g. `ex_input %>% rowid_to_column() %>% pivot_longer(-rowid) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rowid)` Not a solution but might be a good starting point.

Comment: Windowed functions may be helpful here but haven't figured out exactly how to get what's needed out of it. In case it helps others [{runner}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/vignettes/apply_any_r_function.html) seems promising, as does `zoo::rollapply()` and `data.table::frollapply()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can identify the position of run lengths of NA that are less or equal to 4, not at the beginning or end of a row, and assign a "1" to `ex_input` based on those. First I change base `rle` a bit to return a data.frame which is a bit easier to work with.

```
rlen <- function (x) {
  if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x)) stop("'x' must be a vector of an atomic type")
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0L) return(data.frame(lengths = integer(), values = x))
  y <- x[-1L] != x[-n]
  i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n)
  within(
    data.frame(
      lengths = diff(c(0L, i)),
      values = x[i]), {
        end = cumsum(lengths)
        start = c(1, end)[1:length(end)]
      })
}
```

`is.na(ex_input)` converts the data.frame to `TRUE` and `FALSE`, circumventing some annoyances with `rle`. After the `apply` step, we have vectors of positions to be replaced, which can be `NULL`.
Using `imap`, we can access the list index, and insert that in the row slot of `[`, returning invisibly because we are after the side effects.

```
library(tidyverse)
y <- apply(is.na(ex_input), 1, function(x){
  ids <- rlen(x) %>%
    mutate(rnum = seq_along(lengths)) %>%
    filter(rnum != nrow(.) & rnum != 1 & values & end-start <= 4)
  if(nrow(ids) != 0) ids$start:ids$end
})

invisible(imap(y, ~ if(!is.null(.x)) ex_input[.y, .x] <<- 1))
ex_input

# A tibble: 4 x 10
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2    NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
4    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
```

Comment: This solution accepted since it is the most generalizable (i.e. it can solve the problem when values in a row are less than an odd number apart - the other two solutions require an even number apart).  However, a more generalized solution requires replacing ids$start:ids$end  with something like unlist(map2(ids$start, ids$end, seq))  for cases where there are more than one gaps in a row to fill in

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution (though not so elegant in places). I first put the data in a long format. Next, I split the data into a list of dataframes by group (i.e., each row), then I use `shift` from `data.table` to get values from up to 2 rows ahead and 2 rows behind, which then is bound together, then I get the sum of the values. The logic is that if a given cell is `NA`, then there should be at least a sum of 2 from both directions to be able to fill that cell in with a `1`. Then, I `unlist` all of the sums, then bind back to the long form of the data, `df_long`. The first `case_when` is used to find any `sums` that is greater than 2, if so, then change `value` to 1. The second `case_when` is to deal with the D2 and F2, as these would not meet your first criteria of having a 1 in each direction within 4 columns. But we can use `lag` and `lead` to look ahead and behind and if there is a 1 on both sides, then we can change to 1.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df_long <- ex_input %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row)

df <- df_long %>%
  group_split(row) %>%
  map(., function(x) rowSums(do.call(cbind, shift(x$value, -2:2)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  bind_cols(df_long, sums = .) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(value == 1 ~ value,
                           sums >= 2 ~ 1,
                           TRUE ~ NA_real_),
         value = case_when(value == 1 ~ value,
                           lead(value) == 1 & lag(value) == 1 ~ 1,
                           TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-sums) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

**Output**

```
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2    NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
4    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
```

Comment: Nicely done. It looks like `A` `4` is `1` but should be `NA`. Seems very close though!

Comment: @DanAdams Thanks! And thanks for catching that. Just needed a `group_by` before the `case_when` statements.

Comment: Excellent work. After I poked at this for a while I gave up so I'm glad to see something that works!

Comment: @DanAdams Thanks. I was close to giving up at one point! I probably spent too long on it, haha.

Answer (score 1):

This works in base-R (not counting everything being a tibble).

```
for(i in seq(nrow(ex_input))){
  r <- ex_input[i,]
  for(cl in seq(ncol(r))){
    
    if(cl+4 > ncol(r)){break()}
    r2 <- r[cl:c(cl+4)]  
    if(sum(r2, na.rm = T) >= 2){

      colms <- which(colnames(r2) %in% names(r2[which(!is.na(r2))]))
      r[seq(min(colms+cl-1), max(colms+cl-1))] <- 1
      
      ex_input[i,] <- r
    }
  }
}  

ex_input
    
# A tibble: 4 x 10
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2    NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
4    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
```